# Getting method not defined error using dojo lang.hitch

Tags: dojo, amd

I'm pretty new to dojo, and I'm trying to use the lang.hitch method to handle my callbacks, but I keep getting an "Uncaught Reference Error:  is not defined error" when using it.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong - I'm just not sure what it is.  `this` refers to my newly created object in the initializeLocators function, verified as I stepped through my code.  The candidates parameter to the showResults method is returned from the event handling closure. Thanks for your help.

My class:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", ..., "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", ...], 
function(declare, ..., lang, ...){
    var SDCLocateClass = declare(null, {
        ...,
        constructor: function() {
            this.initializeLocators();
        },
        initializeLocators: function() {
            this.addressNode = dom.byId("resultsDiv");


            //set up the address locator functionality
            this.locator = new Locator("http://...");
            this.locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", lang.hitch(this, showResults));
        },
        showResults: function(candidates) {
            ...
        },
    });
    return SDCLocateClass;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showResults` is a variable that is not defined.  Use `this.showResults` or use a string `"showResults"`

```
this.locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", 
    lang.hitch(this, this.showResults));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I wish the docs would explain that better, to make it clear the method name HAS to be a string.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be a string, it needs to be a string or a function. The issue here is not specific to Dojo; `showResults` is not defined in your code. If you tried to use `showResults` anywhere else, you would get the same error.